# If the rank of the linear mapping $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is $2$, then $\dim(\ker \varphi)=1?$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I think that the statement isn't true, because $ \text{rank}(\varphi)=\dim(\text{Im} \varphi)$ so it says nothing about the dimension of $\ker \varphi$.

Comment: If dim Im = 2 then dim Ker = 4 - 2 = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if $\phi$ is *surjective* then the dimension of the kernel is rank $1$. Otherwise, the claim is false, since $\dim \ker(\phi)+\dim( \mathrm{Im}(\phi)=4$. Since by assumption the rank is $2$, we can deduce that the dimension of the kernel is in fact $2$.

Comment: Do you mean $\dim\ker\varphi =1$?

Comment: Does it matter whether or not $\phi$ is surjective?

Comment: If $\phi$ were to be surjective, then it would have rank 3, so why would it even be relevant to the question?

Comment: Excuse me, I misread the question.

Comment: So can I say, that the statement is false, because the statement does not mention that this is surjective?

Comment: Well I guess. You are implicitly just invoking the rank nullity theorem though. Better to just say what the dimension of the kernel *is*.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)